# Is the requirement of being aligned with the EU's foreign policy in order to join it written into law?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, geopolitics, serbia

> The threat Russia poses in the Western Balkans should not be
> exaggerated. Virulent nationalist rhetoric aside, Serbia is not
> beholden to the Kremlin but rather is hedging its bets, as it has done
> for a long time. Moreover, the United States and the EU are running
> out of patience, ramping up pressure on Vučić to come off the fence.
> In Belgrade, von der Leyen stressed that Serbia’s progress toward EU
> accession was contingent on the country’s alignment with the union’s
> foreign policy. However belatedly, the war in Ukraine may mean that
> Yee’s warning is finally heeded.

Is the requirement of being aligned with the EU's foreign policy in order to join it written into law? von der Leyen stressed that Serbia's progress toward EU accession was contingent on the country's alignment with the EU's foreign policy. I was wondering if that requirement is written into law, because Hungary by preventing Sweden to join NATO seems to indicate that they don't always agree, and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to kick countries out of the union on that basis.

Comment: Note that Hungary *lost alignment* with the rest of the EU after accession. Today it would be unlikely to be allowed in. (Or the rest of the EU lost alignment with Hungary and the previous Polish government. The greater numbers are not always right, but 25-2 or 26-1 should give pause for thought.)

Comment: Given the rise in popularity of AfD and Geert Wilders, there's a chance of many other EU nations will flip in the coming decade. The current EU policies depend on pro-socialism/pro-Green/pro-human-rights politicians being in power. Once that changes, the policies will be abandoned.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is part of [Chapter 31 of the acquis](https://neighbourhood-enlargement.ec.europa.eu/enlargement-policy/conditions-membership/chapters-acquis_en). Chapters which compliance is required to join the EU

> The common foreign and security policy (CFSP) and the European security and defence policy (ESDP) are based on legal acts, including legally binding international agreements, and on political documents. The acquis consists of political declarations, actions and agreements. Member States must be able to conduct political dialogue in the framework of CFSP, to **align with EU statements**, to take part in EU actions and to apply agreed sanctions and restrictive measures. **Applicant countries are required to progressively align with EU statements**, and to apply sanctions and restrictive measures when and where required.